# declare a transaction in ejb 3.0

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, persistence, ejb-3.0

how can I force the EJB to not flush everything after every single command, I want to do a transaction. I've read that this is done somehow declaratively. But how exactly?

`@Stateless
public class SomeBean{
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
public void doSomeStuffAndThenFlushToTheDb(){
    em.persist(entity);
    // it's flushed by now, I don't want that
    em.persist(somethingElse);
    // now I want to flush both
    em.flush();
  }
}`

Comment: Which db? Weird results may occur, if your database doesn't support transactions (e.g myisam in mysql)

Comment: If you want to rollback the current transaction, use "@Resource SessionContext context" to inject SessionContext to bean and call context.setRollbackOnly() to rollback.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, how can I force the EJB to not flush everything after every single command, I want to do a transaction.

First of all, you shouldn't get a `flush` after *"every single command"* and I'm actually surprised that you get a `flush`  after the `persist`. Are you showing all the code? Second, EJB methods are transacted by default. But transaction and `flush` are not really related (the only link is that a `flush` will be done before the `commit`). Anyway...

If you would like to control the way a `flush()` call executes, you can change the default flush mode using `EntityManager#setFlushMode()`. The flush modes are as follows:

- `COMMIT` - Flushing occurs only at transaction commit, or when flush() is called.
- `AUTO` - (Default) Flushing occurs before any query execution.

So something like that should work:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeBean {
    ...
    public void doSomeStuffAndThenFlushToTheDb(){
        em.setFlushMode(COMMIT);
        em.persist(entity);
        em.persist(somethingElse);
        em.flush(); // Causes flush
    }
    ...
}
```

But as I said, I'm surprised by your example. The behavior you describe is not what I would expect.

Comment: em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);em.persist(match);
  em.clear();
  em.flush(); , I would expect nothing to be saved in the database in this concise example, but the oposite is the truth, why? When I cleared everything by `em.clear()`?

Comment: @coubeatczech This is an entirely different question that is not easy to discuss in a comment box. Please open another question and mention your JPA provider (but your use case is really weird anyway).

Answer (score 0):

First of all "flush" means only store it the second level cache (db driver). It is not stored directly within the DB. The entity is kept within the cache since the transaction is completed and a commit is sent. "Clear" means detach the entity. It does not mean clear the database. So afterwards you cannot persist this entity anymore. But the persist will still be done at the end of the transaction.

Comment: Actually documentation for flush() says: "Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database". However, flush does not cause commit