# Manage persistent context before flushing

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

consider hibernate-link and JTA as peristence provider. How can I force em not to flush anything, and to handle it by myself?

```
@Stateless 
public class SomeBean{
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;
  public void method(){
    em.persist(entity); // will get managed
    em.clear(); // everything gets unmanaged
  }
}
```

I would expect that there is nothing flushed into the database, but there is as I can see in the mysql shell. So how can I force `EntityManager` not to flush anything after persist?
Thanks
`persistence.xml` for completeness

`<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/fotbalDataSource
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I force em not to flush anything, and to handle it by myself?

As answered in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719376/declare-a-transaction-in-ejb-3-0/3719539#3719539), use `em.setFlushMode(FlushType.COMMIT)` if you want to avoid any automatic `flush` **before** the commit of the JTA transaction (at the end of the EJB method). Just keep in mind that there will be a `flush` at commit time.

> I would expect that there is nothing flushed into the database, but there is as I can see in the mysql shell.

I don't think that the piece of code you're showing illustrates the above question, it's a different question here. Anyway... before going further, here is what the JPA specification says about `clear()`:

```
/**
* Clear the persistence context, causing all managed
* entities to become detached. Changes made to entities that
* have not been flushed to the database will not be
* persisted.
*/
public void clear();
```

So `clear()` causes all managed entities to become **detached**, not **unmanaged**.

In other words, while the spec is a bit cloudy regarding your use case, I don't think that calling `clear()` is supposed to make the entity passed to `persist()` in your code snippet a ***new*** entity again.

I'll test this more extensively tomorrow (even if I think that this use case doesn't make much sense) and will update my answer.

Comment: it looks like a hibernate bug. After I switched to eclipselink, It work as expected

Comment: @coubeatczech Interesting. I really wonder if this is a bug or a difference in the interpretation of the spec. Did you create a Jira issue?

Comment: @coubeatczech Somehow, I'm not convinced that what you "expected" is the right behavior. The JPA spec doesn't define any NEW -> MANAGED -> NEW transition. And because NEW -> MANAGED -> DETACHED requires to make the entity persistent before to detach it, I think Hibernate is actually more correct.